# Is this much (40x) nginx slowdown under HTTPS to be expected?

Tags: nginx, https, ab

So I've created a simple file, ab.htm, with just "test" in it.

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://www.domain.com/ab.htm
```

gives me 15400req/sec

and

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 https://www.domain.com/ab.htm
```

gives me 390req/sec

If I add the -k Keep-Alive flag, it comes back up to ~10,000.  But that's not a solution, if I get 1,000 concurrent users they're not all going to share the same connection...

This is on a 4GB Centos 6 VPS, nginx 1.5.6.

I tried it at concurrencies of 1, 100 & 1000 too and got similar results.

I was expecting it to be slower, but not FORTY times slower.... is this normal, or has something gone horribly wrong? If it is normal, what can I do to improve the situation - weaker cyphers etc I guess?

And yes, I appreciate that this is a tiny part of the puzzle, and relatively insignificant compared to scripting and database loads. But still, I'd like to at least know that it's normal.

Thanks

---

**Additional info:**

- CentOS 6.4
- Intel E5-2640 CPU
- Xen VPS (on a HP DL380p Gen8 Proliant Server, I think)
- 4GB ram

Versions etc:

```
uname -a
```

Linux 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 28 17:19:38 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
openssl version
```

OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

```
nginx -V
```

nginx version: nginx/1.5.6
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-http_spdy_module

Comment: can you add your ssl_config, esp. cipher_suites?

Comment: Other than the SSL certs & private key, I have nothing configured at all.  Just letting it run with its defaults for the time being.

Comment: Which, when I browse to the site in Chrome, tells me this:  "encrypted with 256-bit encryption.  The connection uses TLS1.2.  The connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC, with SHA1 for message authentication and DHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism.

Comment: no cipher_suites?

Comment: I didn't have any set.  I do now, and it's made very little difference, regardless of which ciphers I pick.  Next idea?

Comment: nginx-version? repo or compiled? os? `nginx -V && openssl version`

Comment: Added those and uname/OS under question.

Comment: Oh and I compiled nginx & openssl myself.  I wanted to play with SPDY and couldn't get that support through repos.  But they're not spitting out any errors so I think they're ok...

Comment: ok, nothing suspicious; if your browser tells you "TLS1.2" then you probably use the right ssl-version. i'd sugggest you ask qt the nginx-mailinglist, since you'll find better support, since devs are posting there. you should get an answer quickly. [forum.nginx.org](http://forum.nginx.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a significant slowdown is to be expected but 300 rps is too slow; i did some tests recently and those are my results, to give you some numbers and relations:

- http: ~ 30.000 rps
- https w/out keepalive: ~ 9.000 rps
- https w/ keepalive: ~ 18.000 rps

what your need to do:

- tune the right numbers of workers in nginx.conf (workes == numbers of processors)
- enable [ssl_session_cache shared](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache)
- test different cipher-suites for performance (tbd from my site)
- check out [this guide](http://www.mare-system.de/guide-to-nginx-ssl-spdy-hsts/#optimizing-for-better-ssl-performance) for more nginx-based ssl + perf-tuning-infos

390/rps i'd expect from apache ... SCNR :)

Comment: 1) Already set workers to cores (6)

Comment: 2) Setting "ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;" and restarting nginx made negligible difference.

Comment: ok, then i'd suggest cipher-tuning, and you might want to check with ssllabs.com. and please retest with -c 100

Comment: I've tried a whole bunch of different ciphers now, including some of the weakest ones.  They make very little difference, ranging from 350 to 400 req/sec.

This tells me that the problem isn't with the cipher, but something else that's causing a big delay...